How can I specify a different binary name per platform
I want the cargo install command to create a different binary name on Linux than other platforms.
The reason is that the name of the binary (tc) is also a kernel system utility (/usr/sbin/tc). So I have to install a different binary name and I ask my Linux users to either create an alias tc=termcalc, or to use the termcalc command.
The following doesn't work.
[[target.'cfg(not(linux))'.bin]]
name = "tc"
path = "src/bin.rs"

[[target.'cfg(linux)'.bin]]
name = "termcalc"
path = "src/bin.rs"

